# Linked Server Connection Error(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

[image]

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "bio".OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "bio" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Did it cross your mind that it might be important for others to know exactly how you defined your linked server? And did you ask your coworkers or your dbas for assistance?

Comment: Have this been solved and if so. how.